# How do I seperate drives in my file system (ubuntu server)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid

I recently bought a HP Proliant DL360G6 and it has 3 hard drives. I installed Ubuntu server LTS 20.04 without raid configured and now I realize that all three drives have been merged (idk if thats the right word) together into the filesystem and show as one storage device.

The hard drives are very small as they are quite old but im considering upgrading soon and I also want to setup raid. Im not sure what is happening here and I don't want to try anything incase I stuff something up.

Thanks

[image: Hard Drives]

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you have a RAID controller. You haven't set up software RAID, but there's a hardware RAID underneath which manages things by itself and exposes disks to OS as a single logical device (HP LOGICAL VOLUME).

Look for controller's messages on boot. You have to press *something* to access its settings.

Unfortunately separating disks into independent devices will make data on them unreadable - you'll have to reinstall and restore whatever files you have stored there currently.

Comment: Yea I havent put any files onto it yet so its just the bare operating system. Ill try to setup raid in the boot menu.